# RegEx Matching Multiple Strings in a Large Text File

Tags: c#, .net, regex

### Problem

I have a rather large text file (roughly 10 Megabytes, 700,000 Lines) that has HTML code within it.

My goal is to extract certain information from it. I believe using RegEx would be the best approach to this since I have multiple files I need to do the same too.

I have, what I believe a RegEx that matches the data that I need but I believe I am running into an issue with anchors. I have been using regex101.com to assist me with matching and learning RegEx but I can only match one part of data at a time. I have tried playing with \A, $, ^ for the start and end of the string with no luck. I have tried googling this but I only found one article the seemed to have matched my use case and it was using perl and the solution was to create a single string of the entire text file which I dont believe is a good idea.

### Sample Input File

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body dir="LTR" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<!-- Created by Oracle Reports 04:00 Fri Aug 15 04:00:37 AM, 2014 -->

<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=774>
<tr><td width=15></td><td width=1></td><td width=3></td><td width=6></td><td width=44></td><td width=1></td><td width=15></td><td width=4></td><td width=17></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=14></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=17></td><td width=11></td><td width=4></td><td width=11></td><td width=2></td><td width=13></td><td width=45></td><td width=1></td><td width=15></td><td width=3></td><td width=9></td><td width=8></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=14></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=17></td><td width=12></td><td width=17></td><td width=12></td><td width=45></td><td width=1></td><td width=9></td><td width=6></td><td width=4></td><td width=16></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=13></td><td width=1></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=17></td><td width=12></td><td width=17></td><td width=13></td><td width=36></td><td width=8></td><td width=1></td><td width=15></td><td width=4></td><td width=17></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=14></td><td width=1></td><td width=11></td><td width=1></td><td width=17></td><td width=12></td><td width=17></td><td width=8></td><td width=1></td><td width=10></td><td width=25></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=77 height=9></td></tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9></td>
  <td colspan=23></td>
  <td colspan=2></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=77 height=9></td></tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9></td>
  <td width=174 colspan=19 rowspan=2><font face="helvetica" color="#007f7f"><b>15-AUG-2014</b></font></td>
  <td colspan=38></td>
  <td width=139 colspan=16 rowspan=2 align=center> <font face="helvetica" color="#007f7f"><b>Page&nbsp;</b></font><font face="helvetica" color="#007f7f"><b>1</b></font><font face="helvetica" color="#007f7f"><b>&nbsp;of&nbsp;</b></font><font face="helvetica" color="#007f7f"><b>58</b></font><br></td>
  <td colspan=3></td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9></td>
  <td colspan=38></td>
  <td colspan=3></td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=3></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=3></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=77 height=9></td></tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=2></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=27></td>
  <td colspan=28></td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=4></td>
  <td width=44><font size=2 face="helvetica">08/14/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">7</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">3</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=3 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=45><font size=2 face="helvetica">07/19/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">2</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">4</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=45><font size=2 face="helvetica">06/23/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 colspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=16 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">0</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 colspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">6</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=44 colspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">05/28/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">3</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">1</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=77 height=1></td></tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=4></td>
  <td width=44 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">08/14/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;M</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">4</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">3</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=3 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=45 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">07/19/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;M</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=2 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">6</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=45 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">06/23/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 colspan=2 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;M</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=16 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">7</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 colspan=2 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">8</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">6</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=44 colspan=2 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">05/28/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;M</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">2</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">6</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=4></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=77 height=1></td></tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=4></td>
  <td width=44 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">08/13/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">8</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">6</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=3 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=45 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">07/18/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=2 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">0</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">4</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">3</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=45 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">06/22/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 colspan=2 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=16 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 colspan=2 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=44 colspan=2 rowspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">05/27/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">4</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">2</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=4></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
```

### Regular Expression

Using Global and Multiline Modifers

```
\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d*><font size=\d face="helvetica">(?<Date>\d+.\d+.\d+)<.font><.td>
\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face="helvetica">&nbsp;(?<Time>E|M)<.font><.td>
\s*<td width=\d* colspan=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face="helvetica">(?<FirstNum>\d)<.font><.td>
\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face="helvetica">-<.font><.td>
\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face="helvetica">(?<SecondNum>\d)<.font><.td>
\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face="helvetica">-<.font><.td>
\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face="helvetica">(?<ThirdNum>\d)<.font><.td>
```

### C# Source

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string filePathDirty = @"DataBase/InputFile.htm";
    string filePathClean = @"DataBase/InputFile-CLEAN.htm";

    int totalLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePathDirty).Length;

    try
    {

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePathDirty);
        string cleanLine;

        int progress = 0;

        string pattern = String.Empty;

            // Group Name: Date
            pattern += @"\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d*><font size=\d face=""helvetica"">(?<Date>\d+.\d+.\d+)<.font><.td>";
            // Group Name: Time
            pattern += @"\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face=""helvetica"">&nbsp;(?<Time>E|M)<.font><.td>";
            // Group Name: FirstNumber
            pattern += @"\s*<td width=\d* colspan=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face=""helvetica"">(?<FirstNum>\d)<.font><.td>";
            pattern += @"\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face=""helvetica"">-<.font><.td>";
            // Group Name: SecondNumber
            pattern += @"\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face=""helvetica"">(?<SecondNum>\d)<.font><.td>";
            pattern += @"\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face=""helvetica"">-<.font><.td>";
            // Group Name: ThirdNumber
            pattern += @"\s*<td width=\d* rowspan=\d* align=right><font size=\d* face=""helvetica"">(?<ThirdNum>\d)<.font><.td>";

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Skip the First 69 Lines, No Need to Since there is no Data
            if (progress > 69)
            {

                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, pattern))
                {
                        cleanLine = String.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4}\r\n", match.Groups["Date"].Value, match.Groups["Time"].Value, match.Groups["FirstNum"].Value, match.Groups["SecondNum"].Value, match.Groups["ThirdNum"].Value);
                        WriteToFile(cleanLine, filePathClean);
                }

            }

            progress++;

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

}
```

### Simplified Specifications

Within the HTML there is a very little bit of Data that needs to be extracted. I have commented to help identify where that data is and how it is formatted.

```
<!-- Start Matching -->

<tr valign=top>
  <td height=9 colspan=4></td>

<!-- Line Below Has the Date // 08/14/14 -->

  <td width=44><font size=2 face="helvetica">08/14/14</font></td>
  <td></td>

<!-- Line Below Has the Time // E -->
<!-- Will Either be a Capital E or M for Evening or Morning -->

  <td width=15 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>

<!-- Line Below Has the First Number // 5 -->

  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>

<!-- Line Below Has the Second Number // 7 -->

  <td width=14 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">7</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>

<!-- Line Below Has the Third Number // 3 -->

  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">3</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=3 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>

<!-- End of Matching // There are Three Sets of Data per HTML Table Row -->

  <td width=45><font size=2 face="helvetica">07/19/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 colspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">9</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">2</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">4</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=45><font size=2 face="helvetica">06/23/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 colspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=16 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">0</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 colspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">6</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=44 colspan=2><font size=2 face="helvetica">05/28/14</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=15 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;E</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">5</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=14 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">3</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=11 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">-</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">1</font></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width=17 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
```

I want to group these sets to Create a New Flat File in the Following Format to cleanly Import into a Database.

Date | Time | NumberOne | NumberTwo | NumberThree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about another approach..

1. First convert the HTML document/HTML TABLE to XML ( we can get the free tools/code to  do this
2. write your own XQuery/XML parsing code to get the details you want and do the rest of the job.
   Hope this helps..

Comment: Good to hear.. :) Good luck :)